# How do I use RestKit's object mapping when I have object roots?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

RestKit's object mapping works great when my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "users" : [
                  {
                      "first_name": "John",
                      "last_name":  "Doe"
                  },
                  {
                      "first_name": "Bill",
                      "last_name":  "Smith"
                  }
              ]
}
```

However, my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "users" : [
                  {
                      "user": {
                                  "first_name": "John",
                                  "last_name":  "Doe"
                               }
                  },
                  {
                      "user": {
                                  "first_name": "Bill",
                                  "last_name":  "Smith"
                               }
                  }
              ]
}
```

I haven't been able to find anyway to get RestKit's object mapping to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to map an Array of user objects.  User should have the two properties.  How are you mapping it?